# How does Google OAuth2.0 callback works in iOS app?

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I wanna know how an iOS app grabs authorization grant after being called back from Safari after authorization with Google when using [GoogleSignIn](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn) package.

I followed [instructions on google's developer site](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) that tells me to add following code to AppDelegate, which I believe is responsible for handling that.

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
   openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
      return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
         sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
         annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
}
```

But when I placed a breakpoint to this method, so I could see the url, it was never called. I even tried to delete this method and it still works!

Can somebody explain to me what kind of magic is that?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Google Login in one of my application in following way...

Required pod

`pod 'GoogleSignIn'`

**User Tap On Google Login Button**

I've created custom button.

```
@IBAction func btnGoogleSignInTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kGoogleClientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

**GIDSignInDelegate Implementation**

```
extension MyVC: GIDSignInDelegate {

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email

        debugPrint("user id = \(String(describing: userId))")
        debugPrint("idToken = \(String(describing: idToken))")
        debugPrint("fullName = \(String(describing: fullName))")
        debugPrint("givenName = \(String(describing: givenName))")
        debugPrint("familyName = \(String(describing: familyName))")
        debugPrint("email = \(String(describing: email))")

        //sign in successfull......
    } else {
        debugPrint("Google sign in error :\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    debugPrint("User did disconnecte with error !!")
}

//-----------------------------------------------------
}
```

you need to set URL Type under info.plist file of your project...

[image]

Comment: Well thank you but my problem is **not** that it wouldn't work. I don't understand how does it work. How this `sign(_:didSignInFor:withError:)` func gets called after return from Safari?

Comment: You need to set `URL Types` under Info.plist file....The steps are given by goolge when we setup app.

Comment: You don't understand my question. After invocation my app with URL `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:])` in AppDelegate should be called, right? But it's not. And it still works. How? How does the app know that it was called back from Safari?